# Only the creator of a Trello board can edit workloads?

Tags: trello

We are trying to edit the workload on our cards, but only the creator of the board can see and edit them correctly. The rest of us are all tagged as Admin members, but we see the workload as this:

(20) TASK

Is this intended or a bug?

Comment: What do you mean by workload? Is this something you have added in the description?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, we actually discovered it was an extension called "Scrum for Trello" that was installed by the board leader without him remembering getting it... So, mystery solved! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually a Chrome extension called [Scrum for Trello](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jdbcdblgjdpmfninkoogcfpnkjmndgje).